# Control flow of for loops

Tags: python

I am writing a pseudo code where I want the below two "for" loops to be repeated until all the keys in data_changes and modem_changes are same, i.e. there should not be any keys that are present data_changes but not in modem_changes and vice versa.  I should be able to write the Python implementation after this; can anyone provide inputs?
EDITED:

am more interested in

1. how to call func1 and func2 for keys that are present in one and not the other

2.repeating the for loops until the keys are the same in data_changes and modem_changes

```
data_changes = {
    '253036': [''], 
    '313115': ['313113']
    }

modem_changes = {'305403': [], 
                 '311957': ['253036', '312591']
                 }

s1 = set(data_changes.keys())
s2 = set(modem_changes.keys())
value1 = s2.difference(s1)
print value1
value2 = s1.difference(s2)
print value2

def func1 (data_changes,key):
    if key == '311957':
        output = ''
    if key == '305403':
        output = ''
        return output

def func2 (modem_changes,key):
    if key == '313115':
        output =''
    if key == '253036':
        output=''
    return output

def method(d1, f1, d2, f2):
    s1 = set(d1.keys())
    s2 = set(d2.keys())
    for k in s2.difference(s1):#set(['311957', '305403'])
        f1(d1, k) # k in d2 not in d1.
    for k in s1.difference(s2):#set(['313115', '253036'])
        f2(d2, k) # k in d1 not in d2.

while(True):
    method(data_changes, func1, modem_changes, func2)
    value = set(data_changes.keys()) - set(modem_changes.keys()) 
    print value
    if value == set([]):
        break;


EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

data_changes = {
    '253036': [''], 
    '313115': ['313113']
    '305403':[''] 
    '311957':['']
    }

modem_changes = {'305403': [], 
                 '311957': ['253036', '312591']
                 '253036':[]
                 '313115':[] 
                 }
```

Comment: @Mike - its not only intersection of two sets..there is much more am trying..am more confused about the control flow on how this can be achieved..

Comment: `data_changes.update(modem_changes)` ;-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro - what does update do?

Comment: It takes the data of modem changes and merges it into data_changes. The resulting data_changes will have the keys from both (and the values from modem_changes, except where they were missing. http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update

Comment: Sorry but I just dont see what is the problem here. You know how to use a dict don't you ? I mean, at least the most basic operations ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: No he doesn't. This is clearly somebody trying to learn programming. And it's OK to ask newbie questions on SO for that. This may be a bit too localized, but it's probably more likely a duplicate, but those can be hard to find.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - no problem her,this looks like a big problem to me :-) ... trying to learn

Comment: What should be the effect of func1 on modem_changes?

Comment: @jimifiki - it will add keys and some dependent changes to modem_changes

Comment: @user2125827 I tried to make your question clearer with a couple of edits, I hope I set the question on the right trails

Comment: @user2125827 You should never modify your original question so as to change its meaning. This question has now lost all hope of every being answered correctly. I recommend you open a new question and more succinctly explain your problem, including ALL you code, and any errors/stacktrace you have, Your sample input, and expected output / what you are getting instead. I can help you no further here, because you are simply missing a few concepts and understanding at the moment/ So please, make a new question, link it as a comment,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [8]: keys = set(data_changes.keys()) & set(modem_changes.keys())

In [9]: data_changes = {k:data_changes[k] for k in keys}

In [10]: modem_changes = {k:modem_changes[k] for k in keys}

In [11]: data_changes
Out[11]: {'253036': ['']}

In [12]: modem_changes
Out[12]: {'253036': ['311957', '312994', '312591']}
```

Comment: am more interested in 1.calling func1 and func2 for keys that are present in one and not the other 2.repeating the for loops until the keys are the same in data_changes and modem_changes

Comment: @user2125827: You can still use this technique. For example, `set(data_changes.keys()) - set(modem_changes.keys())` will give you the keys found in `data_changes` but not in `modem_changes`.

Comment: ..ok thanks..that will solve my problem#1.. how to keep repeating the two "for" loops until the keys are the same in data_changes and modem_changes,i.e there are no changes are in one and not other...if not this way..any other better way to implement?

Comment: so if "set(data_changes.keys()) - set(modem_changes.keys()) = 0" means the keys are the same ,this can be my exit condition,am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to keep repeating the for loops:

```
while(True):
    for key in data_changes:
        if key not in modem_changes:
            func1()
    for key in modem_changes:
        if key not in data_changes:
            func2()
    if(True): #logic to check wether to run for loops again
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not explained what exactly you mean by "keys are the same" I will assume that `func1` and `func2` are functions that you have already written and use them in my answer as such. I also assume the functions take the dictionary/key they are working on. If this is not the case, you can always change it at your code.

```
def method(d1, f1, d2, f2):
    s1 = set(d1.keys())
    s2 = set(d2.keys())
    for k in s2.difference(s1):
        f1(d1, k) # k in d2 not in d1.
    for k in s1.difference(s2):
        f2(d2, k) # k in d1 not in d2.
```

The method above takes arguments in the following form, illustrated by your examples:

```
method(data_changes, func1, modem_changes, func2)
```

---

If you mean that all keys that are not in both dictionaries should be removed, then one of the following code snippet should do it for you:

```
def keep_similar(d1, d2):
    '''creates new dicts from shared keys'''
    shared_keys = set(d1.keys()).intersection(set(d2.keys()))
    r1 = dict((k, d1[k]) for k in shared_keys)
    r2 = dict((k, d2[k]) for k in shared_keys)
    return (r1, r2)

def eliminate_diffs(d1, d2):
    '''removes non-shared keys from dicts'''
    s1 = set(d1.keys())
    s2 = set(d2.keys())
    for k in s2.difference(s1):
        del d2[k]
    for k in s1.difference(s2):
        del d1[k]
    return (d1, d2)
```

Simply choose the one that most suits your case, if you have few similar keys, then use the first, if you have few non-similar keys, then use the second.

Comment: Remember that `s2.difference(s1) == s2 - s1`, and `s1.intersection(s2) == s1 & s2`

Comment: @Inbar Rose - "keys are same meaning"...any key present in one should be present in other...number of keys should be same and equal..doesnt have to be in the same order

Comment: @user2125827 Yes, but should keys be added, or removed? If added, what values should they have?

Comment: @InbarRose - keys will be added and for the added keys these for loops should be repeated until the keys are the same...

Comment: And if they are added, what should their values be? (have you even ran my code to check if it works?)

Comment: @InbarRose - am running your code now... their values will also e some integers...

Comment: @InbarRose - I updated the current code..its running in an infinite loop currently..